# Prove the maximum length of a subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pigeonhole-principle

I am having problems with this problem in my book.
It says:
If I have $n^2 +1$ distinct real numbers $a_1, a_2,...,a_{n^2+1}$. Assume that there is no increasing subsequence of length $n+1$. Let $j_i$ be the length of the longest increasing subsequence that starts at $a_i$. Prove that $1 \leq j_i \leq n$. I have no idea how to approach this problem. It is part of a bigger proof I am trying to do, but I am lost. 
Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: If your $j_i$ is $\geq n+1$, then you can pick an increasing subsequence of length $n+1$ from this sequence.

Comment: So just contradiction and that's it?

Comment: I dont know, it seems so, but I suggest you to check your problem again, it shouldn't be like this simple.

Comment: That is literally all that appears in the book for that part of the problem, haha.